# How to check the actual queries Qcache_not_cached

Tags: mysql, caching

How can I check which queries query_cache didn't cache? 
my Qcache_not_cached is very large and I would like to know which queries are not cached and why.

```
| Qcache_not_cached              | 12843     |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run the status of Qcache_not_cached and show status like 'Qcache_hits' before and after your queries. If you see the cache size increased then the query is being cached and if the size remains the same then it's not.